# I need to detect which Polygon the marker in using flutter_map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, polygon

I'm using flutter_map and Polygon to draw areas on the map i can detect if the marker in Polygon but I need to know which Polygon the marker in like area name
when I start move the marker

I'm using flutter_map and Polygon to draw areas on the map i can detect if the marker in Polygon but I need to know which Polygon the marker in like area name
when I start move the marker

my code is

```
final List<Point> points = <Point>[
 Point(y:25.230139, x:55.325258),
    Point(y:25.230089, x:55.325323),
    Point(y:25.229844, x:55.324948),
    Point(y:25.229736, x:55.324980),
    Point(y:25.229608, x:55.325008),
    Point(y:25.229525, x:55.324991),
]

FlutterMap(
                      options: MapOptions(
                        minZoom: 12,
                        maxZoom: 18,
                        keepAlive: true,
                        zoom: 18,
                        center: LatLng(25.229795867928427, 55.32376579660171) ,
                        interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.pinchZoom | InteractiveFlag.flingAnimation | InteractiveFlag.drag,
                        //enableScrollWheel: true,
                          onPositionChanged: (v,vw){
                          _marker2Position = v.bounds!.center;
                          print(Poly.isPointInPolygon(Point(y:v.bounds!.center.latitude,
                              x:v.bounds!.center.longitude), points));
                          if (Poly.isPointInPolygon(Point(y:v.bounds!.center.latitude,
                              x:v.bounds!.center.longitude), points)){
                            isPark = true;
                            setState(() {});
                          } else {
                            isPark = false;
                            setState(() {});
                          }
                          }
                        //allowPanningOnScrollingParent: false,
                      ),
                      children: [
                        TileLayer(
                          userAgentPackageName: 'X4 Car Rental',
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.4),
                          urlTemplate:
                          "https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/hamadadxb/clrrw95fy00hp01r42pz49bj1/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoiaGFtYWRhZHhiIiwiYSI6ImNsbDgyc2cwdjE0YTUza21raGx4Z24zcGsifQ.e6kJpWNZuqOO7IqfKms5aA",
                          additionalOptions: {
                            'mapStyleId': AppConstants.mapBoxStyleId,
                            'accessToken': AppConstants.mapBoxAccessToken,
                          },
                        ),
                        // MarkerLayer(
                        //   markers: [
                        //     Marker(
                        //       height: 60,
                        //       width: 60,
                        //       point: LatLng(25.229795867928427, 55.32376579660171),
                        //       builder: (_) {
                        //         return GestureDetector(
                        //           onTap: () {
                        //
                        //             setState(() {});
                        //           },
                        //           child: AnimatedScale(
                        //             duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        //             scale: 1,
                        //             child: AnimatedOpacity(
                        //               duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                        //               opacity: 1,
                        //               child: Image.asset('assets/images/carMaerkerIcon.png')
                        //             ),
                        //           ),
                        //         );
                        //       },
                        //     ),
                        //   ],
                        // ),
                        PolygonLayer(
                          polygonCulling: true,
                          polygons: [
                            Polygon(

                              points: [
                                LatLng(37.422206, -122.086055),
                                LatLng(37.422156, -122.086092),
                                LatLng(37.422126, -122.086202),
                                LatLng(37.422185, -122.086305),
                                LatLng(37.423055, -122.086285),
                                LatLng(37.423018, -122.086040),
                              ],
                                color: Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2),
                                borderStrokeWidth: 4,
                                borderColor: Colors.blue,
                                isFilled: true
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        PolygonLayer(
                          polygonCulling: true,
                          polygons: [
                            Polygon(
                                labelPlacement:PolygonLabelPlacement.values.first,
                                label: '331B',
                                points: [
                                  LatLng(25.230139, 55.325258),
                                  LatLng(25.230089, 55.325323),
                                  LatLng(25.229844, 55.324948),
                                  LatLng(25.229736, 55.324980),
                                  LatLng(25.229608, 55.325008),
                                  LatLng(25.229525, 55.324991),
                                  LatLng(25.229441, 55.324970),
                                  LatLng(25.229353, 55.324921),
                                  LatLng(25.229286, 55.324842),
                                  LatLng(25.229254, 55.324758),
                                  LatLng(25.229235, 55.324668),
                                  LatLng(25.229235, 55.324535),
                                  LatLng(25.229242, 55.324440),
                                  LatLng(25.229254, 55.324332),
                                  LatLng(25.229276, 55.324215),
                                  LatLng(25.229343, 55.323805),
                                  LatLng(25.229402, 55.323365),
                                  LatLng(25.229473, 55.322860),
                                  LatLng(25.229512, 55.322722),
                                  LatLng(25.229615, 55.322564),
                                  LatLng(25.229714, 55.322502),
                                  LatLng(25.229768, 55.322494),
                                  LatLng(25.229871, 55.322491),
                                  LatLng(25.229994, 55.322521),
                                  LatLng(25.230043, 55.322542),
                                  LatLng(25.230131, 55.322667),
                                  LatLng(25.230156, 55.322719),
                                  LatLng(25.230168, 55.322936),
                                  LatLng(25.230097, 55.323371),
                                  LatLng(25.230075, 55.323544),
                                  LatLng(25.230027, 55.323853),
                                  LatLng(25.229959, 55.324533),
                                  LatLng(25.229917, 55.324706),
                                  LatLng(25.229848, 55.324725),
                                  LatLng(25.229878, 55.324574),
                                  LatLng(25.230091, 55.322941),
                                  LatLng(25.230091, 55.322762),
                                  LatLng(25.230005, 55.322605),
                                  LatLng(25.229883, 55.322566),
                                  LatLng(25.229676, 55.322608),
                                  LatLng(25.229618, 55.322676),
                                  LatLng(25.229572, 55.322755),
                                  LatLng(25.229545, 55.322874),
                                  LatLng(25.229543, 55.322869),
                                  LatLng(25.229324, 55.324442),
                                  LatLng(25.229318, 55.324572),
                                  LatLng(25.229338, 55.324729),
                                  LatLng(25.229400, 55.324808),
                                  LatLng(25.229494, 55.324863),
                                  LatLng(25.229563, 55.324891),
                                  LatLng(25.229728, 55.324858),
                                  LatLng(25.229827, 55.324762),
                                ],
                                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.2),
                                borderStrokeWidth: 0.5,
                                borderColor: Colors.amber,
                                isFilled: true
                            ),
                            Polygon(
                                labelPlacement:PolygonLabelPlacement.values.first,
                                label: '331D',
                                points: [
                                  LatLng(25.228556, 55.322842),
                                  LatLng(25.228551, 55.322950),
                                  LatLng(25.227685, 55.322861),
                                  LatLng(25.227718, 55.321850),
                                  LatLng(25.227928, 55.321894),
                                  LatLng(25.227898, 55.322677),

                                ],
                                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.2),
                                borderStrokeWidth: 0.5,
                                borderColor: Colors.amber,
                                isFilled: true
                            ),
                            Polygon(
                                labelPlacement:PolygonLabelPlacement.values.first,
                                label: '331C',
                                points: [
                                  LatLng(25.227136, 55.321506),
                                  LatLng(25.227143, 55.321423),
                                  LatLng(25.227055, 55.321405),
                                  LatLng(25.226801, 55.321566),
                                  LatLng(25.226743, 55.321659),
                                  LatLng(25.226790, 55.321722),

                                ],
                                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.2),
                                borderStrokeWidth: 0.5,
                                borderColor: Colors.amber,
                                isFilled: true
                            ),
                            Polygon(
                                labelPlacement:PolygonLabelPlacement.values.first,
                                label: '331X',
                                points: [
                                  LatLng(25.230446, 55.322002),
                                  LatLng(25.229851, 55.321847),
                                  LatLng(25.229860, 55.321726),
                                  LatLng(25.230461, 55.321839),
                                ],
                                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.2),
                                borderStrokeWidth: 0.5,
                                borderColor: Colors.amber,
                                isFilled: true
                            ),
                            Polygon(
                                labelPlacement:PolygonLabelPlacement.values.first,
                                label: '331X',
                                points: [
                                  LatLng(25.230600, 55.321751),
                                  LatLng(25.230580, 55.321842),
                                  LatLng(25.230096, 55.321753),
                                  LatLng(25.230105, 55.321654),
                                ],
                                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.2),
                                borderStrokeWidth: 0.5,
                                borderColor: Colors.amber,
                                isFilled: true
                            ),
                            Polygon(
                                labelPlacement:PolygonLabelPlacement.values.first,
                                label: '331X',
                                points: [
                                  LatLng(25.228737, 55.323640),
                                  LatLng(25.228849, 55.323664),
                                  LatLng(25.228708, 55.324847),
                                  LatLng(25.228601, 55.324837),
                                ],
                                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.2),
                                borderStrokeWidth: 0.5,
                                borderColor: Colors.amber,
                                isFilled: true
                            ),
                            Polygon(
                                labelPlacement:PolygonLabelPlacement.values.first,
                                label: '331Y',
                                points: [
                                  LatLng(25.228534, 55.324798),
                                  LatLng(25.228450, 55.324788),
                                  LatLng(25.228635, 55.323255),
                                  LatLng(25.228704, 55.323260),
                                ],
                                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.2),
                                borderStrokeWidth: 0.5,
                                borderColor: Colors.amber,
                                isFilled: true
                            ),
                            Polygon(
                                labelPlacement:PolygonLabelPlacement.values.first,
                                label: '331Y',
                                points: [
                                  LatLng(25.226393, 55.325403),
                                  LatLng(25.226335, 55.325858),
                                  LatLng(25.230098, 55.326421),
                                  LatLng(25.230137, 55.325930),
                                ],
                                color: Colors.amber.withOpacity(0.2),
                                borderStrokeWidth: 0.5,
                                borderColor: Colors.amber,
                                isFilled: true
                            ),

                          ],
                        ),
                        MarkerLayer(
                          //key: GlobalKey<DragMarkerWidgetState>(),
                          markers: [
                            Marker(
                                height: 60,
                                width: 60,
                                point: _marker2Position,
                                builder: (_){
                                  return GestureDetector(
                                    onTap: () {
                                      print('Marker Tapped');
                                      setState(() {});
                                    },
                                    onHorizontalDragUpdate: (v){
                                      print(v);
                                      print(_marker2Position);
                                    },
                                    child: AnimatedScale(
                                      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                      scale: 1,
                                      child: AnimatedOpacity(
                                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                          opacity: 1,
                                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/carMaerkerIcon.png')
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                }

                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
```

my results

[image]

I need to detect which Polygon the marker in using flutter_map

thank you
best regards